# Javascript button for toggling Class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new at html/css/js and I have been doing a project tutorial to learn the content. I looked at other JS button issues but I'm not sure how it applies to my case (since I'm new).

The project has us create a robot that has flashing eyes once a button is clicked. If that button is clicked again then the flashing stops.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poller+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
...

/* Other parts of robot */

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
    background-size: 75px 150px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
    background-size: 75px 150px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
    background-size: 75px 150px;
  }
}

.laser {
  animation: blink 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 5s infinite;
}
.brain {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, white 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, white 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5; 
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
  background-size: 75px 150px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 60px 60px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #666;
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
}
.foot {
...
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="robot">
  <div class="beep"></div>
  <div class="brain"></div>
  <div class="torso">
    <div class="left">j</div>
    <div class="right">j</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot"></div>
</div>

<button class="flash">laser eyes on/off</button>
<button class="color">change color!</button>

<script>
// Button to toggle
$('.flash').click(function() {
  $('.brain').toggleClass('laser');
});

</script>

</body>
```

I am wondering if there's anything in particular that is wrong as I am unsure how to correct it even though I have placed everything in the right place, according to the tutorial. There was a mention of including more CSS identifies in HTML elements but I'm not sure how that would change anything here.

Comment: the .laser selector is missing the closing brace }, and when you use prefixed properties like -webkit you should place them before the standard ones (animation: should go after -webkit-animation and -moz-animation)

Comment: `keyframes` not appear defined for `blink` animation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again a case of not wrapping your jQuery code within `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Change your jQuery code to,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.flash').click(function() {
  $('.brain').toggleClass('laser');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poller+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
...

/* Other parts of robot */

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
    background-size: 75px 150px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
    background-size: 75px 150px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
    background-size: 75px 150px;
  }
}

.laser {
  animation: blink 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 5s infinite;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="robot">
  <div class="beep"></div>
  <div class="brain" height="50px">df</div>
  <div class="torso">
    <div class="left">j</div>
    <div class="right">j</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot"></div>
</div>

<button class="flash">laser eyes on/off</button>
<button class="color">change color!</button>

<script>
// Button to toggle
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.flash').click(function() {
  $('.brain').toggleClass('laser');
});
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I did that and it's still not working. There's nothing I have to do in `<body>` to define `laser`?

Comment: Thats because there's nothing in the div to be shown.Add height/width, some content. See the edit please

Comment: I have a class called `.brain` that makes no specific mention of `.laser`. Would it be okay to use, say my `.foot` class there? I'll try it out but I wanted to ask why specifically it needs `.brain`.

Comment: Sorry but I didn quite get your question! I would say you can go ahead and add but I am just about not sure of what you are asking. Sorry, can you elaborate that please?

Comment: In the jquery, it states `$('.brain').toggleClass('laser')`. Now above when you look at `.brain`, it doesn't specifically mention the `laser` class. Why does `.brain` toggle `laser`? Can any other class toggle `laser`?

Comment: what `$('.brain').toggleClass('laser');` is doing is grabbing the element by using `$('.brain')` and adding/removing the `.laser` class to it. So to answer , * Why does .brain toggle laser?* and *Can any other class toggle laser?*  yes any class can be added/removed to any element? If you were to do, `$('.foot').toggleClass('laser');`, then `.laser` would be applied/removed to/from element with class, `.foot`.